# Read Excel (.xlsx or .csv) with groovy

Tags: java, groovy

How can I read and perform a loop through an excel file with groovy language ? I have read a lot but I could not find an easy way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do worse than starting with [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), which provides a Java API around Microsoft Office docs.